# How to convert a UUID that saved in an array of bytes into a string (c++)

Tags: c++, guid, uuid

I have a UUID that saved as a 16 byte data like this:

```
   unsigned char uuid[16]; //128-bits unique identifier
```

and I want to convert it to a std::string. I can probably write a loop to go thought all bytes and generate the string, but I am looking for a simpler/faster solution. Is there any such solution?

Comment: It is on windows, but is there any solution which is platform independent?

Comment: Voting to close as "unclear what your asking" because the question is ambiguous. Folks who provided an answer to the question "convert to a string" were down voted. Its definitely not fair to the folks who answering the question.

Comment: @jww the question is perfectly clear.

Comment: @Laszlo - You should read through some of the answers and observe the changing requirements.

Comment: @jww Yepp. Horstling has the answer. IMHO, it is more helpful to point out that there are unconventional ways to represent UUIDs as a string in the answer itself. After all, the OP might not be aware of that, and it should not invalidate their question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really want to avoid a loop, you can always do something like:

```
char str[37] = {};
sprintf(str, 
"%02x%02x%02x%02x-%02x%02x-%02x%02x-%02x%02x-%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x", 
    uuid[0], uuid[1], uuid[2], uuid[3], uuid[4], uuid[5], uuid[6], uuid[7],
    uuid[8], uuid[9], uuid[10], uuid[11], uuid[12], uuid[13], uuid[14], uuid[15]
);
```

Not really elegant, but i think it's the best you can get without loop and without platform dependency.

Comment: This is the correct answer, if the UUID is stored as big-endian, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Encoding

Answer (score 2):

Answer on this question is wrong by all means.

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Format

This is the correct code:

```cpp
char str[37] = {};
unsigned long data1 = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(uuid);
unsigned short data2 = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned short*>(uuid + 4);
unsigned short data3 = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned short*>(uuid + 6);
sprintf(str, 
"%08x-%04x-%04x-%02x%02x-%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x", 
    data1, data2, data3,
    uuid[8], uuid[9], uuid[10], uuid[11], uuid[12], uuid[13], uuid[14], uuid[15]
);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to give a different end result than the accepted answer.

Comment: @Sammi It gives a very different end result, test before commenting.

Comment: How do you think I found out that it doesn't have a different result?

Answer (score 1):

Write a loop. For each byte, snprintf of %#02x. Do not forget the conventional dashes.

There is no platform-independent (i.e. POSIX) API that formats UUIDs, so this is the best you are going to get.

Comment: I already suggested this approach in my question, but I am looking for a simpler/faster solution.

Answer (score 0):

basic_string supplys this constructor:

```
basic_string(const E *s, size_type n, const A& al = A());
```

So you can do it like this:

```
string strUuid(uuid, 16);
```

Comment: This is not working! Each char should be converted to two hex value and then appended to string.

Comment: The UUID string has an established format, which this doesn't conform to.

Comment: @mans - you did *not* specify you wanted it hex encoded. wuqiang gave you the correct answer for the question you asked. If you want a particular encoding, then you need to specify it in the question. He surely should not be downvoted for answering the question as it was asked.

Comment: @mans - no, its not. Its 16 octets, just like you showed with `unsigned char uuid[16]`. See, for example, [RFC 4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt). If you want it encoded, then you need to specify how you would like it.

Comment: @jww  but there is a standard way to represent them in string and it is not what this code is doing.

Comment: @mans - two things. First, your code is not doing anything. For all we know, you want the UUID in a string so you can pass it around without the worry of memory management. (That happens to be what I thought, too). Second, there are different ways to encode them to display to the user. (Look at any robust UUID/GUID parser).